# Microsoft graph: The PATCH target $value specified and page content related to the specified PATCH target cannot be located

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I ran into this error when I updating OneNote page content. But let me explain my input HTML for OneNote first before I show you the issue.

Here is my input HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object data-id="markdown-file" data-attachment="markdown.md" data="name:markdown" type="text/markdown" />
        <div data-id="content">{{ content goes here }}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I sent the following patch command to update content if `div[data-id="content"]` exists:

```
{
    'target': generated id of div[data-id="content"],
    'action': 'replace',
    'content': '<div data-id="content">{{ actual content }}</div>'
}
```

otherwise, I use another command:

```
{
    'target': 'body',
    'action': 'append',
    'content': '<div data-id="content">{{ actual content }}</div>'
}
```

Most of time, it works fine. But sometimes not. Suppose we have the following output html:
HTML

```
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>2</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body data-absolute-enabled="true" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt">
        <div id="div:{bbed3bc8-6ec5-4900-b1ee-a11259b4d796}{2}" data-id="_default" style="position:absolute;left:48px;top:120px;width:624px">
            <object data-attachment="markdown.md" type="text/markdown" data="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('195d63c8-4d1e-4073-b535-5d8a32b6f6ce')/onenote/resources/1-5ae390556d1e4351b358b6e1a667a226!1-051437c2-f608-445d-b537-e68aea2dfcd9/$value" data-id="markdown-file" />
            <div data-id="content" id="div:{ce16905b-a76b-4e35-86de-1a46b5f8a62f}{69}:{ce16905b-a76b-4e35-86de-1a46b5f8a62f}{81}">
                <table id="table:{ce16905b-a76b-4e35-86de-1a46b5f8a62f}{69}" style="border:1px solid;border-collapse:collapse">
                    <tr id="tr:{ce16905b-a76b-4e35-86de-1a46b5f8a62f}{70}">
                        <td id="td:{ce16905b-a76b-4e35-86de-1a46b5f8a62f}{72}" style="background-color:white;border:1px solid;text-align:center"><span style="font-family:BlinkMacSystemFont;color:#363636;font-weight:bold">Head</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="tr:{ce16905b-a76b-4e35-86de-1a46b5f8a62f}{71}">
                        <td id="td:{ce16905b-a76b-4e35-86de-1a46b5f8a62f}{75}" style="background-color:white;border:1px solid"><span style="font-family:BlinkMacSystemFont;color:#363636">Column</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice that `div[data-id="content"]` **only** contains a table. If I try to replace `div[data-id="content"]`, it shows the error `The PATCH target $value specified and page content related to the specified PATCH target cannot be located`. The error message is not quite clear, so I cannot know which target is missing.

But if the output HTML contains not only tables, but also other elements, it can be replaced successfully. My code works with the following output HTML:

```
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>3</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body data-absolute-enabled="true" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt">
        <div id="div:{a61d7d65-215f-4936-a8c3-4dda9a805827}{249}" data-id="_default" style="position:absolute;left:48px;top:120px;width:624px">
            <object data-attachment="markdown.md" type="text/markdown" data="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('195d63c8-4d1e-4073-b535-5d8a32b6f6ce')/onenote/resources/1-c52b2dd5a8d74a89a0e038373b52b3f1!1-051437c2-f608-445d-b537-e68aea2dfcd9/$value" data-id="markdown-file" />
            <div data-id="content" id="div:{25489f27-57fa-4798-b4ef-d229a5c5841f}{171}:{25489f27-57fa-4798-b4ef-d229a5c5841f}{187}">
                <table id="table:{25489f27-57fa-4798-b4ef-d229a5c5841f}{171}" style="border:1px solid;border-collapse:collapse">
                    <tr id="tr:{25489f27-57fa-4798-b4ef-d229a5c5841f}{172}">
                        <td id="td:{25489f27-57fa-4798-b4ef-d229a5c5841f}{174}" style="background-color:white;border:1px solid;text-align:center"><span style="font-family:BlinkMacSystemFont;color:#363636;font-weight:bold">Head</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="tr:{25489f27-57fa-4798-b4ef-d229a5c5841f}{173}">
                        <td id="td:{25489f27-57fa-4798-b4ef-d229a5c5841f}{177}" style="background-color:white;border:1px solid"><span style="font-family:BlinkMacSystemFont;color:#363636">Column</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p id="p:{25489f27-57fa-4798-b4ef-d229a5c5841f}{187}" style="margin-top:5.5pt;margin-bottom:5.5pt"><span style="font-family:BlinkMacSystemFont;color:#4a4a4a">hello</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The only difference of two output html is the second one has a p tag. This issue seems weird.

Here is my code to update page content:

```
def update_page(id):
    original_content = _get_page_content(id)
    original_document = PyQuery(original_content)
    content_div = original_document('div[data-id="content"]')
    page = request.json
    new_document = PyQuery(page['content'])

    commands = [
        {
            'target': 'title',
            'action': 'replace',
            'content': page['title']
        },
        {
            'target': '#markdown-file',
            'action': 'replace',
            'content': MARKDOWN_FILE_OBJECT_HTML
        }
    ]

    content = '<div data-id="content">{0}</div>'.format(
        OneNoteHtmlMapper(new_document).get_html()) # OneNoteHtmlMapper is not implemented, it simply calls new_document.outer_html()

    if content_div:
        commands.append({
            'target': content_div.attr('id'),
            'action': 'replace',
            'content': content
        })
    else:
        commands.append({
            'target': 'body',
            'action': 'append',
            'content': content
        })

    files = {
        'Commands': ('', io.StringIO(json.dumps(commands)),
                     'application/json'),
        'markdown': ('markdown.md', io.StringIO(page['markdown']),
                     'text/markdown')
    }

    oauth_client = oauth.microsoft_graph
    response = oauth_client.request(
        'PATCH', 'me/onenote/pages/{0}/content'.format(id), files=files)

    return response.content, response.status_code
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A temporary fix: append a 1px * 1px white image to div if it only contains tables.